# How to create .install custom file

Tags: 8, database

How do I create and add an .install file for Drupal 8 custom form data storage?

My file is *custom_form.install*, but my custom module doesn't load this file.

```php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_schema().
 */
function custom_form_schema() {
  $schema=array();
  $schema['custom_form'] = array(
    'description' => 'An example form table',
    'fields' => array(
      'fe_id' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a form.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'firstName' => array(
        'description' => 'A field storing text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'lastName' => array(
        'description' => 'A field storing text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'emailId' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'pass' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'likes' => array(
        'description' => 'A field storing Likes',
        'type' => 'text',
        'length' => 200,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'gender' => array(
        'description' => 'A field storing Gender',
        'type' => 'text',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'description' => array(
        'description' => 'A field storing Description',
        'type' => 'text',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('fe_id'),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Comment: I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong direction.
Try using drupal 8 configuration system instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the schema using the following code

```
$schema = Database::getConnection()->schema();
$schema->createTable('custom_form', $spec);
```

For further details visit [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2535384)

Comment: This is for updating a schema, not for installing a schema.

Answer (score 0):

This should just work. But it only works when you install the module. If you have your module already installed on a site, you either need to re-install it or write an update function that creates the table too.

You also might want to consider defining a content entity type instead, then you can let it build a form for you using field widgets and it also takes care of storing the data for you.